# What is a contiguous subarray?

Tags: terminology, arrays, maximum-subarray

What is a contiguous subarray? I have tried searching online and have found pages about solving the largest contiguous subarray problem but none with a definition or explanation of what **contiguous** in this actually is.

Ex: [Wikipedia: Maximm subarray problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) has no explanation of why the given "subarray" is **contiguous** or what contiguous means in the context.

Comment: I believe it's just a contiguous (in order) subset of the set.  The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) you referenced, in the first paragraph gives an example: _"For example, for the sequence of values −2, 1, −3, **4, −1, 2, 1,** −5, 4; the contiguous subarray with the largest sum is **4, −1, 2, 1**, with sum 6."_

Comment: Nicely explained with program: 
http://javabypatel.blogspot.in/2015/08/find-largest-sum-contiguous-subarray-using-Kadane-algorithm.html

Answer (score 9):

This is just the ordinary dictionary definition of "contiguous": all adjacent in space. A subarray is defined by any subset of the indices of the original array; a contiguous subarray is defined by an interval of the indices: a first and last element and everything between them.

Comment: This answer is **misleading** in the sense that a subarray, in most articles/books/videos/programming languages/situations, means a contiguous slice of the original array. Sometimes people write contiguous subarray for the sake of extra clarity, which is a bad practice. If one want to be clearer, write contiguous subsequence instead. All respectable definitions of a subarray that I can remember require the indices selected be contiguous. On the other hand, a subsequence is (overwhelmingly if not always) defined without that requirement.

Comment: I agree with John, a *subarray* is an *array*, i.e. implicitly contiguous. For a non-contiguous selection of elements, you might say *subset* if order need not be preserved and *subsequence* if it does.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:**
I get what people are saying.  The actual definition of contiguous subarray is any sub series of elements in a given array that are contiguous ie their indices are continuous.

So given [1,2,3,4,5,6]:

[1,2,3], [3,4], [3,4,5,6] are all valid contiguous subarrays.  Any algorithm can be used to generate the subarrays.

Personal note:
What was confusing for me was most explanations either use or reference a specific problem or condition set to generate the subarrays.  Most don't specifically state there's no direct relationship between the problem and the definition of contiguous subarrays.

For me it's the same as asking:

Q: "What does + do?"

A: "4+4=8"

Me: "OK, so I can only use + with 4, got it."

This is how my brain worked to grok the definition, so hopefully it helps someone else out.

**ORIGIONAL ANSWER:**

OK from what I've worked out the term "contiguous subarray" is a misnomer.

Subarray = "any part or section of an array"
Contiguous = "data that is moved or stored in a solid uninterrupted block."

But AFAIK "Contiguous" still needs to be qualified by further conditions.

For example [this](https://gist.github.com/P-A-R-U-S/d349c516345ba9223797503a12d7f97f) Facebook/Meta test question:

> Contiguous Subarrays
>
> You are given an array a of N integers. For each
> index i, you are required to determine the number of contiguous
> subarrays that fulfills the following conditions:
>
> The value at index i
> must be the maximum element in the contiguous subarrays, and These
> contiguous subarrays must either start from or end on index i.

Or [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/contiguous-array/) LeetCode Example:

> Given a binary array nums, return the maximum length of a contiguous
> subarray with an equal number of 0 and 1.

So just asking for "contiguous subarray" **without** the conditions of what makes a subarrary contiguous is invalid.

Comment: No additional qualifications are needed; it is perfectly fine to refer to a "contiguous subarray" without any further conditions.  I don't understand what additional qualifications you think are needed when using the phrase "contiguous", or why you think that.  Your examples don't demonstrate that additional qualifications are needed.  "what makes a subarray contiguous"  makes no sense to me.

Comment: So for both the problems above, if I just gave you an array and literally just said "Find the contiguous subarray(s)" without any conditions would you be able to solve it?  I guess my point isn't about the definition of "contiguous subarray" and more that people on the internet tend to use that term as a catch all, often inferring conditions without explicitly stating them.

Comment: "I don't understand what additional qualifications you think are needed when using the phrase "contiguous", or why you think that.":  "contiguous" could mean "all the elements of the same color" or "all elements higher than the current element but only of lower index"...

Comment: I realize the exact definition of "contiguous" doesn't need qualification, but when the term "contiguous subarray" is used in the context of a problem, it means some rules must be applied to the original array to generate the subarrays.  Most questions of Stack Overflow etc aren't asking: "what's a contiguous subarray?",  they're asking: "what's a contiguous subarray as applied to a specific problem with specific conditions?"  Now if you don't know that and think contiguous subarray has some inherent algorithmic value it get's confusing.

Comment: You try to force a meaning that does not exist. Taking another examples, a "diagonal dominant square matrix" is square, regardless the extra property of being diagonal dominant. I don't think that the OP is focusing on a specific case, be it the maximum subarray problem.

Comment: I get what people are saying, I'll edit my answer.  Please feel free to add feedback to the edit.